# Make "it has invalid flags" Stand out more

Tags: feature-request

Can we either:

1. Re-order the "**it has invalid flags**" in the list? Or
2. Re-word it so it stands out? "**Mark flag as Invalid**"
3. Perhaps give it a color treatment to make it stand out from the rest since it is a very different operation.

[image]

I only just now noticed that it was an option among the others. I've been trying to figure out how to disagree with a flag.

Yes, I know reading is fundamental, SMH. I do think at the least an additional treatment to the option like color or something would help.

Of course, now that I know it's there, maybe this is a moot point.

Comment: Consider this flagged.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. I had to ask in the chat about how to `disagree with flag` one time and still forget its there.

It should really be at the bottom with different treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps  better wording might be

> I am flagging this answer because...
>
> - I disagree with existing flags

or something a little less subjective like

> - the existing flags are wrong
> - it has been invalidly flagged